# What was this mysterious food/dessert product in 1990s Finland?

Tags: dessert, food-identification, history, jelly

Throughout the 1990s, I often visited Southern Finland with my family. More specifically, Hanko/Hangö.

In the stores, in the refrigerated area, they sold these yummy-looking desserts, or possibly food products. I'm not fully sure what they were, and I'm unsure if we ever bought any of them. (As a non-spoiled child, every little coin was precious to me and not to be "wasted" unless I could be completely sure in advance that it would taste good.)

I'm now trying to find out what these were called, and/or a photograph of the product. I don't remember any kind of branding/label or anything.

All I remember is that it was like a transparent plastic "circular" package, more or less approximating the dimensions of a normal (not too large) dining plate, but "thicker" (taller). It contained some sort of red "goo", possibly/probably some sort of jelly, with milk (or something resembling milk) poured around/over it, which looked extremely nice visually, the way the red and white parts were not muddled together but kept separated.

I don't think it was simply "klappgröt"/"vispipuuro", which they also sold in a similar manner, but that was more pinkish and separate from this dish: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/Klappgr%C3%B6t.jpg/1280px-Klappgr%C3%B6t.jpg

This is probably a long shot, but hopefully, somebody might be able to know what this was called. Even if you do, however, it might not be possible for me to find a photo online, since it might very well be a very local and obscure product. You know, one of those many things which just cannot be found online no matter how much time you spend. Perhaps it was even made in-store and had no actual "trademark".

Comment: may we assume you've tried something like Google Images searches for "Finnish desserts"? (the new thing I learned for today is the Finnish M40 desert camo... and how to correctly spell dessert)

Comment: Since you said "nice visually", I'm not gonna suggest mämmi... But actually, that would fit (and is usually eaten with cream).

Comment: @phipsgabler Hmm... "mämmi" appears to be way too dark red. This was much more bright red.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8dgr%C3%B8d

Comment: @Morran yeah, it's not at all red, but brown, hence my hesitation.

Answer (score 3):

So, I asked someone I know from Finland, and while they also suggested Vispipuuro at first, they followed up with something that sound even more accurate.

It's called "Cranberry Kissel", and is bright red, goo-like, and fits your description pretty well.
[image: bright red goo in a plate-sized pan]
[This is Finnish recipe site](https://www.kotikokki.net/reseptit/nayta/41142/%C3%84idin%20karpalokiisseli/) that I got the photo from also suggests that you can add in whipped cream or something like that, which could be where you got the white aspect from.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is that you were thinking of (as [johannes-b](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/27482/johannes-b) also suggested) Rødgrød, which is from Denmark and northern Germany (though could have conceivably made it's way to Finland).

By the photo found on [this site](http://blog.hihostels.com/2018/09/a-taste-of-scandinavia/), there's definitely the red & white components that you recall, though appears less "goo"-like, and has the berries in it.  The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8dgr%C3%B8d) does comment that [Kissel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/117672/48468) is a related dish to it commonly made in Finland (among other places).
[image: milk or cream poured on top of a red berry-based food]